# How does data get stored in online exams or tests in real time when the connection's OFFLINE?

Tags: offline, offline-caching, offline-mode

I'd like to know how or where data gets stored in an online TIMED exam or test when the network connection becomes offline! I've seen scenarios where the network connection suddenly drops down and when the user logs into his account again, finds that the he can resume his test from the point the connection went offline! So, where does the data of his answers to his previous questions actually get stored? Is it in the client or server side? Do the test providers use any offline storage for these?

I was just curious about this (and kinda new to this) and couldn't find any accurate explanations for this in any search engine. A li'l guidance would be much helpful! [This could really be some kinda basic question I'm sorry for my ignorance- but I really don't know]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the particular exam/system in question, the answer will be a bit generalized. Here goes:
The client side (code running in the browser most likely) must be saving the answers directly to the server as they come in.
The client side can also be linked to the server where the test results are stored. This can be done via a live link such as websockets. Once the server detects that the client is 'down' (for whatever reason) the server may or may not stop the timing of the test. It all depends on the specifics of the particular test. Care to share which?

Comment: Well, to tell you honestly, I  had developed a program using Indexed db, and my professor was like "These kind of applications already exist in online tests!" and scorned at me! So, i just wanted to find if online tests use client-side offline storage alone. Thank you very much for your encouraging reply :)

Comment: Saving on the client side could be problematic. Special permission request(s) would have to pop. Not to mention the results would be open to hacking. Storing such data on the server would be less prone to hacking/cheating. IMHO said teacher should be ignored. One must reinvent the wheel a few times to get good at problem-solving. Rote learning only gets us so far. Just because it is already done doesn't mean you can't learn a whole lot by doing yourself.